# Fetch request to PocketBase fails from terminal but works in Postman and the browser | Next.js13

Tags: node.js, next.js, localhost, pocketbase, undici

I'm building a Next.js app using `create-next-app@latest` with **PocketBase** as the database.

My Problem is that my local PocketBase instance refuses the connection from my NextJS app, but has no problem retrieving data when I fetch it using **Postman** or the **browser**. The issue seems to have to do with the `undici` library though I'm not certain if its the actual source of the issue.

The **fetch** request **only seems to fail** when I try connecting to **localhost**, but any external links such as **`google.com` work fine**.

Here are the code snippets that cause the error

```
async function getNotes(){
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8090/api/collections/notes/records');
    const data = res.json();
    return data;
}
```

```
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase';

async function getNotes(){
        const pb = new PocketBase('http://127.0.0.1:8090')
        const list = await pb.collection('notes').getList(1, 100, {});
        return list;
}
```

Error log when using the built-in fetch API

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8090
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8090
  }
}
```

Error log when using the PocketBase ORM

```
ClientResponseError 0: Something went wrong while processing your request.
    at new ClientResponseError (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/pocketbase/dist/pocketbase.es.mjs:161:23)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/pocketbase/dist/pocketbase.es.mjs:1619:39)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getNotes (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/notes/page.tsx:21:22)
    at async NotesPage (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/notes/page.tsx:31:19) {
  url: '',
  status: 0,
  response: {},
  isAbort: false,
  originalError: TypeError: fetch failed
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8090
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1574:16)
        at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
      errno: -111,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8090
    }
  }
}
```

Error log when using the 'node-fetch' npm library (the error log doesn't include Undici this time)

```
FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/collections/notes/records?page=1&perPage=30 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8090
    at ClientRequest.eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:124:20)      
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  erroredSysCall: 'connect'
}
```

I've tried just about everything I could find such as:
1. Changing node versions and updating local and global npm packages
2. Using 3rd party libraries such as 'node-fetch' and 'axios' to connect to the database.
3. Connecting to the database using the PocketBase npm package (ORM) and also using just the fetch API after running PocketBase. Note that the admin panel works fine.
4. Changing between `http://localhost:....` and `http://127.0.0.1:...` urls gives exactly the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to pin point the source of the issue,

However, it seems that switching to a non-chromium based browser is a valid workaround for the time being

This is the [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7982) with more information about the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the behavior change in recent versions of NextJS.
Check that there is a value set for the **HOSTNAME** environment variable.
If yes and it is different from **localhost**, the node will not open the port on the local address (localhost) and there will be no connection through the local IP (127.0.0.1). You can test by setting HOSTNAME with the "localhost" value.

Answer (score 0):

Do `pb.autoCancellation(false);`
Disabling auto-cancellation is generally not recommended as it can lead to unexpected behavior if multiple requests interfere with each other.

check network while requesting this api. There may be multiple calls.
You can learn more from here - https://github.com/pocketbase/js-sdk#auto-cancellation

`isAbort: true`: indicates intentional cancellation by the SDK,
`isAbort: false`: can arise due to other network connectivity or server-side issues.

```
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase';

async function getNotes(){
  pb.autoCancellation(false);
  const pb = new PocketBase('http://127.0.0.1:8090')
  const list = await pb.collection('notes').getList(1, 100, {});
  return list;
}
```