Unable to get full list of users using NextJs with pocketbase?
Standalone index.js usage of pocketbase is working
I have a pocketbase instance running with few users created in dashboard. And I have created a standalone index.js in an npm project like so(I have installed pocketbase sdk as well)
const PocketBase = require('pocketbase/cjs');

const pb = new PocketBase('http://127.0.0.1:8090');

const main = async () => {
    const authData = await pb.admins.authWithPassword('admin@gmail.com', '<pass>');
    console.log(" ~ main ~ authData:", authData)
    console.log(await pb.collection('users').getFullList());
};

main();

And when I run node index.js, I get the authData printed as expected and I also get the full list of users printed as well.

Similar nextjs usage of pocketbase not working
Now I have created a new nextjs project(from their docs, it uses the new app router). And then I have created a src/lib/pbClient.ts like so
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase';

export default async function initPocketBase() {
  const pb = new PocketBase('http://127.0.0.1:8090');
  const authData = await pb.admins.authWithPassword('admin@gmail.com', '<pass>');
  console.log(' ~ main ~ authData:', authData);
  console.log(await pb.collection('users').getFullList());
}

And then in one of the main page.tsx files I have something like below
import initPocketBase from '@/lib/pbClient';

export default async function Home() {
  const pb = await initPocketBase();
  return <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">Main Page</main>;
}

Now when I check the nextjs logs(in the server), I only see authData being printed, but the users full list is an empty array(its being printed as []). So at least I know that I am able to connect to pocketbase since admins authData is printing, but full list of users are not being printed. I thought this might be an issue with ListRule access in pocketbase but I dont think thats the case because in standalone index.js example(first example above) it works perfectly fine.
So is this an issue with nextjs or some finicky stuff with async-await in pocketbase?
Posted it on their github as well: link

So if I change pocketbase host url from 127.0.0.1 to localhost, then it seems to work. Not sure why this is the case. This SO answer had the hint https://stackoverflow.com/a/76862703/6059506
